# Populate various XML message structures from single Object using XSD schema C# .Net

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd, schema

I have an application that needs to send information from housed in one object to various APIs which each have different structures for the XML messages they accept. I also have a bunch of .xsd files corresponding to each type of message for each API.

For example, the class with all the information looks like this:

```
class Class1
{
    public string s1;
    public string s2;
    public string s3;
    public string s4;
}
```

One API will accept the information in a format like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="IBM437"?>
<Class1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <s1>first string</s1>
    <s2>second string</s2>
    <s3>third string</s3>
    <s4>fourth string</s4>
</Class1>
```

While another will accept the information like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="IBM437"?>
<Class1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <s1>first string</s1>
    <s2>second string</s2>
    <OtherStrings>
        <s3>third string</s3>
        <s4>fourth string</s4>
    </OtherStrings>
</Class1>
```

I'm looking for a way to programmatically transform the object Class1 into the various types of messages based on the schema. Is there anything that can help me do this, or do I need to parse the schemas myself?

I'm trying to avoid using xsd.exe so if the schema ever changes or new ones are added, I will not have to generate new classes and change the code that generates the messages. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to produce XML files to send over to different APIs? So producing a xml file and conforming it to a schema before sending it over?

Comment: Yup that's what i'm going for